# How to bring the SSRS reports developed to EPICOR?

Tags: reporting-services, epicorerp, epicor, epicor10

I'm new to EPICOR. I have developed a report in SQL Server Report Builder. How can I view this report in my EPICOR account? How does it link?

Thanks In advance

Niki

Answer (score 3):

You can upload your report rdl file in Custom Reports folder. 
And then create a menu in Epicor, select the Program Type as SSRS Custom Report link and give URL Path to your report.

Hope it helps!